# Is there a better way to unpack a binary string in Python

Tags: python, struct, stream, type-conversion

At the moment I have a byte stream of a string that is received by my Python code and must be converted into a string. For now I managed to extract each character, convert them and append them to a string individually. The code looks something like this:

```
import struct

# The byte stream is received and stored in byte_stream

text = ''
i = 0
while i < len(byte_stream):
    text = text + struct.unpack('c', byte_stream[i])[0]
    i += 1

print(text)
```

But that surely cannot be the most efficient way... Is there a more elegant way to do achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1):

From [Convert bytes to a Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-python-string):

```
byte_stream = [112, 52, 52]
''.join(map(chr, bytes))
>> p44
```

Comment: On that page I found the following code that worked :) Many thanks `byte_stream.decode('utf-8')` I cannot believe I didn't find that out myself...